# Object [object Object] has no method 'test'

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use a function in another module i am not able to use it may i know what is the issue?

```
 this.test = function(callback) {
        callback('i am test');
    };
    module.exports.config = function (settings, callback) {
    this.test(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
    });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is different because you're inside another function. Try this instead:

```
this.test = function(callback) {
  callback('i am test');
};
var self = this;
module.exports.config = function (settings, callback) {
  self.test(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Or just give the function name and call it directly:

```
function test(callback) {
  callback('i am test');
};
module.exports.config = function (settings, callback) {
  test(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```