# Callback is not working it is printing as undefined

Tags: node.js

I had a previous question [Object [object Object] has no method 'test'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372270/object-object-object-has-no-method-test) Now the issue with object is gone but the call back is not working the console.log prints **undefined**

```
this.test = function(callback) {
  callback('i am test');
};
var self = this;
module.exports.config = function (settings, callback) {
  self.test(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Please ignore as i am new to nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.test()` expects a callback that will be passed a string as the first argument.  You are giving it a callback function that uses the second argument, not the first argument.  Since no second argument is passed to the callback, you get `undefined` for it.

Change your call from this:

```
  self.test(function(err,res){
    console.log(res);
  });
```

to this:

```
  self.test(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Or, alternatively change the implementation of `this.test()` to pass a second argument to its callback.

```
this.test = function(callback) {
  // pass two arguments to the callback
  callback('i am test', 'this is me');
};
var self = this;
module.exports.config = function (settings, callback) {
  self.test(function(err,res){
    // now both arguments err and res are available here
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example to pass a second argument to callback?

Comment: @Ramesh - example of passing two arguments to the callback added to the end of my answer.